# Issue with ConstraintLayout (max width, dimension ratio and chain style)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am having an issue with ConstraintLayout and a specific view.

What is wanted : 3 imageviews in a 6:5 ratio, the first one is bigger with the two other stacked vertically on its right. The whole view has a maxed width of 414dp.

When trying to set the horizontal chain style at packed, the views don't display at all over 414dp. 
There is no issue under that limit or with a chain style other than packed.

Here are

- the layout :https://gist.github.com/xcaEi/ba46e5e8c2d1d5682e1a5f3221325ed0
- screenshots of the problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsHRB.jpg

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want, I believe you must nest a `ConstraintLayout` inside another `ConstraintLayout`.

The problem is that you can't have both `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` and `layout_constraintWidth_max` defined on the same view; each of these is one option for how to constrain a view set to "match constraints".

> **MATCH_CONSTRAINT dimensions *(Added in 1.1)***
>
> When a dimension is set to `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`, the default behavior is to have the resulting size take all the available space. Several additional modifiers are available:
>
> - `layout_constraintWidth_min` and `layout_constraintHeight_min`: will set the minimum size for this dimension
> - `layout_constraintWidth_max` and `layout_constraintHeight_max`: will set the maximum size for this dimension
> - `layout_constraintWidth_percent` and `layout_constraintHeight_percent`: will set the size of this dimension as a percentage of the parent

(From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)

You can work around this by having your inner `ConstraintLayout` specify its maximum width, and then have the `ImageView` children of that inner ConstrainLayout specify their percentages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#eee"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="414dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_imageview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#caf"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,6:5"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.666"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/second_imageview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#fac"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/main_imageview"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/main_imageview"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/third_imageview"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,6:5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/third_imageview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="#afc"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/second_imageview"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/main_imageview"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/main_imageview"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,6:5"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your need [3 imageview first one bigger](https://ibb.co/cvPZaq). You  can change layout_constraintHorizontal_weight properties  check below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="6:5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="6:5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="6:5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it but this does not work with chain style packed. Also the two small images are stacked on each other rather then next to each other so it might explain why it doesn't work.